Can I repair or paint bluestones with efflorescence?
The bluestone at the entrance to my house has very stubborn efflorescence. I have tried to clean it using white vinegar and muriatic acid mixed with water: one part acid to eight parts water. I scrubbed the test stones on my hands and knees with a coarse brush and it came right back.
Can repair or paint the stones with a solid paint and then seal them to prevent efflorescence?



Effervescence: tonic water. Efflorescence: minerals drying out.

What problem does this cause that's less undesirable than a bland painted floor which will wear out in a year or two and need repainting?

Efflorescence comes from the concrete underneath. You can keep cleaning it with vinegar. OR dig up the tiles, coat the concrete and replace the tiles. OR talk to the supplier of Acquron. It can make such surfaces water proof. You have to coat the grout as well.
